# Calculate the average % of a compounded increase with Excel formulas

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to calculate the average % of a compounded increase.

For example, if $100 increases by 5% over three years, the average % increase over the whole period is **10.34%**.

> 100.00 + 5% = 105.00, 105.00 + 5% = 110.25, 110.25 + 5% = 115.76, AVERAGE(105,110.25,115.76) = 110.34, (110.34 - 100) / 100 = **10.34%**

I'm currently calculating this with lots of IF statements because duration, percent, and starting values are variable…

```
=((100*1.05+IF(3>=2,100*(5/100+1)^2)+IF(3>=3,100*(5/100+1)^3))/3-100)/100
```

*my actual formula contains many, many more lines to catch durations up to 25 years which is why I'm looking to scale it down with some intelligent calculations*

The results will be shared with other teams who don't use VBA, so needs to utilize in-built formulas. 
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Your basic formula would be:

```
=(AVERAGE(FV(0.05,{1,2,3},0,-100))-100)/100
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Now if one wants the inputs to be dynamic(pointed at input cells) then we need to change the formula a little:

```
=(AVERAGE(FV(B2,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B1)),0,B3))+B3)/(-B3)
```

Still an array formula

[image]

---

NOTE: If one has the dynamic array formula SEQUENCE it can be done without the need of CSE with:

```
=(AVERAGE(FV(B2,SEQUENCE(B1),0,B3))+B3)/(-B3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The math solution is

```
=((1+R)^N-1)*(1+R)/(R*N)-1
```

where R is the rate and N is the number of periods.